# Creating a function which creates a new column based on the values of other columns in a dataframe and determining invalid values

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

Here is a simplified version of the DF in question:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'type': ['terrier', 'toy','toy','toy', 'hound' , 'terrier', 
                            'terrier', 'terrier','terrier', 'hound'],
                            'breed' : ['yorkshire_terrier', 'king_charles_spaniel', 'poodle', 'shih_tzu',
                            'greyhound', 'west_highland', 'bull_terrier' , 'fox_terrier', 
                            'west_highland', 'afghan'],
                   'colour' : ['pink', 'orange','brown','purple', 'grey' , 'white', 
                               'black', 'cream','brown', 'brown']})
    
df


    type         breed                  colour
0   terrier     yorkshire_terrier       pink
1   toy         king_charles_spaniel    orange
2   toy         poodle                  brown
3   toy         shih_tzu                purple
4   hound       greyhound               grey
5   terrier     west_highland           white
6   terrier     bull_terrier            black
7   terrier     fox_terrier             cream
8   terrier     west_highland           brown
9   hound       afghan                  brown
```

Using the function below, I am able to create a new `new_colours` column with the rules presented in these dictionaries

Dictionaries:

```
toy = {'black' : ['poodle', 'shih_tzu'], 
       'mixed' : 'king_charles_spaniel',
       'white' : ['poodle', 'shih_tzu']}

terrier = {'black_brown' : ['yorkshire_terrier','bull_terrier'],
           'white' : 'west_highland',
           'white_orange' : 'fox_terrier'}

hound = {'brindle' : 'greyhound',
           'brown' : 'afghan'}
```

Function:

```
def colours(x):
    for dog in [hound,toy,terrier]:
        for colour in dog:
            if x in dog[colour]:
                return colour

df['new_colour']=df['breed'].map(colours)
```

Output:

```
    type    breed                 colour    new_colour
0   terrier yorkshire_terrier     pink      black_brown
1   toy     king_charles_spaniel  orange    mixed
2   toy     poodle                black     white
3   toy     shih_tzu              purple    black
4   hound   greyhound             grey      brindle
5   terrier west_highland         white     white
6   terrier bull_terrier          black     black_brown
7   terrier fox_terrier           cream     white_orange
8   terrier west_highland         brown     white
9   hound   afghan                brown     brown
```

The problem here, however, is with poodle (much more cases in real DF in question). According to the rules presented in the dictionaries, a poodle can be `white` or `black`. It was originally labeled, in the `colour` col as being `black` - but the `new_colour`says `white`which is possible but I would like to have the original `colour`column as the correct colour.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let’s first generate all the tuples of allowed configurations:

```
>>> ok_tuples = [(breed, color) for color, breeds in {**toy, **terrier, **hound}.items()
...                             for breed in (breeds if type(breeds) is list else [breeds])]
...
>>> df_colors = pd.DataFrame(ok_tuples, columns=['breed', 'colour'])
>>> df_colors
                  breed        colour
0                poodle         black
1              shih_tzu         black
2  king_charles_spaniel         mixed
3         west_highland         white
4     yorkshire_terrier   black_brown
5          bull_terrier   black_brown
6           fox_terrier  white_orange
7             greyhound       brindle
8                afghan         brown
```

That way we can with a simple `.merge` find which colours are allowed:

```
>>> df.merge(df_colors, how='left', on=['breed', 'colour'], indicator=True)
      type                 breed  colour     _merge
0  terrier     yorkshire_terrier    pink  left_only
1      toy  king_charles_spaniel  orange  left_only
2      toy                poodle   brown  left_only
3      toy              shih_tzu  purple  left_only
4    hound             greyhound    grey  left_only
5  terrier         west_highland   white       both
6  terrier          bull_terrier   black  left_only
7  terrier           fox_terrier   cream  left_only
8  terrier         west_highland   brown  left_only
9    hound                afghan   brown       both
>>> colour_ok = df.merge(df_colors, how='left', indicator=True)['_merge'].eq('both')
```

Now we can keep the allowed colours with `.where` or remove them with `.mask`:

```
>>> df['colour'].where(colour_ok)
0      NaN
1      NaN
2      NaN
3      NaN
4      NaN
5    white
6      NaN
7      NaN
8      NaN
9    brown
Name: colour, dtype: object
>>> df['colour'].mask(colour_ok)
0      pink
1    orange
2     brown
3    purple
4      grey
5       NaN
6     brown
7     black
8     cream
9       NaN
Name: colour, dtype: object
```

So we can finally merge to get the `new_colour` and then use `.mask` to restore the values that were already correct:

```
>>> assign_new_colour = df_colors.drop_duplicates(subset=['breed']).rename(columns={'colour': 'new_colour'})
>>> df = df.merge(assign_new_colour, on='breed')
>>> df['new_colour'] = df['new_colour'].mask(colour_ok, df['colour'])
>>> df
      type                 breed  colour    new_colour
0  terrier     yorkshire_terrier    pink   black_brown
1      toy  king_charles_spaniel  orange         mixed
2      toy                poodle   brown         black
3      toy              shih_tzu  purple         black
4    hound             greyhound    grey       brindle
5  terrier         west_highland   white         white
6  terrier         west_highland   brown         white
7  terrier          bull_terrier   black   black_brown
8  terrier           fox_terrier   cream  white_orange
9    hound                afghan   brown         brown
```

Answer (score 1):

You can modify your `colours` function:

```
def colours(x):
    possibilities=[]
    for dog in [hound,toy,terrier]:
        for colour in dog:
            
            if x in dog[colour]:
                possibilities.append(colour)
            
    if df[df.breed==x].colour.values[0] in possibilities:
        return df[df.breed==x].colour.values[0]
    else:
        return possibilities[0]
```

This assumes that the dataset on which you are working is named `df`, othewise you can pass it as an argument to `colours`:

```
def colours(x,df):
    possibilities=[]
    for dog in [hound,toy,terrier]:
        for colour in dog:
            
            if x in dog[colour]:
                possibilities.append(colour)
            
    if df[df.breed==x].colour.values[0] in possibilities:
        return df[df.breed==x].colour.values[0]
    else:
        return possibilities[0]

df['new_colour']=df['breed'].map(lambda x: colours(x,df))
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. Unfortunately I'm getting ```IndexError: list index out of range``` when applied to my df in question.

Comment: My code works with the data you provided, if you want a more general answer, you can share your whole code